# Sending Tasks using an offline Outlook

Tags: outlook

I've a scenario wherein I need to send/assign tasks from my browser UI to the concerned. This should happen with Outlook being offline (or for that matter outlook not even configured on the terminal) so that the user can be accessing a workflow from any terminal (using his/her AD credentials) and if required should have the ability to send a task to the concerned without having to return to his own terminal to be able to do so.

I envision that the user's credentials should be used to look up the AD for his/her email ID and send a task using the same from anywhere in the intranet.

Using Outlook object library I have been able to assign/send tasks, but with the Outlook being fired up and not otherwise.

Redemption does the sync of contacts while Outlook is offline but not tasks.

Kindly help if anybody has had a chance to do something similar.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Redemption could help you here as you can run it it on a web server which will connect to you exchange env via mapi for you.

There are other ways dependant on you version of exchange EWS or Exchange DAV.
[EWS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204040(v=EXCHG.80).aspx) comes with a [managed API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd637749(EXCHG.80).aspx) now a days to take some of the sting out of it. 
There are similar 3rd party libraries for [Exchange DAV](http://www.independentsoft.de/webdavex/index.html) as well.

They all contain contact and directory lookups.

Comment: Sorry, I dont quite understand .. why would exchange be un-available ? What I was explaining is that you run a web server that runs your task app, this would need a connection to exchanage as would remeption etc.